# Shortcut to switch to a certain opened file in Brackets

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, ide, brackets

In Emacs, assume we have several files loaded, we could switch to buffer by `Ctrl+x b`, then type the first letters of a file name, and then `TAB`.

In Brackets, we could go through opened files by `Ctrl+TAB`, but I am wondering if there is a way to switch like in Emacs: by typing the first letters without having to look at the screen.

I understand it is quite specific, but I am new to Brackets, maybe it's already doable but I didn't know...

Comment: Have you seen this [page of shortcuts](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/brackets-shortcuts)? Did you try with the extension `Ctrl-Shift-E`?
Maybe you can find useful even the extension Quick Navigate and `brackets-tabs` (the second to reorder the tabs so you can switch directly between the interesting versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Navigate => Quick Open` whose short-cut is `shift+cmd+o` is the closest to what I am after...

Answer (score -1):

on Mac OSX:

`COMMAND + SHIFT` then `] / }`